# Notification not showing when my alarm triggers onReceive()

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to pop up a notification when my alarm manager fires my onReceive() method. This is what I have done

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire(10000);

    startNotification(context);

    wl.release();

}


public void setAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(Activity, "MainActivity.class");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    assert am != null;
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60000, pi);
}


private void startNotification(Context context){
    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

            // Build Notification , setOngoing keeps the notification always in status bar
    mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle("RandomTitle")
                    .setContentText("RandomText")
                    .setOngoing(true);

    // Create pending intent, mention the Activity which needs to be
    //triggered when user clicks on notification(StopScript.class in this case)

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("extra","Extra Notificacion");
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   // context.startActivity(notificationIntent);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
     notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Android Oreo
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Im really confused why this notification is not showing, I have tested my alarm and it triggers after 1 minute of beign created, but the notification is still not showing.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Which OS is the app running on?

Comment: android nougat 7.1

Comment: Can you tell me your `targetSdkVersion` in gradle?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android developer:

> When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or
>   more notification channels. If your targetSdkVersion is set to 25 or
>   lower, when your app runs on Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, it
>   behaves the same as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level
>   25) or lower.

Because your `targetSdkVersion` is 28, so you must add `channelId` in the `Builder` constructor  too.

Change your code to:

```
// Build Notification , setOngoing keeps the notification always in status bar
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notify_001") // Add channel ID to the constructor.
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setContentTitle("RandomTitle")
        .setContentText("RandomText")
        .setOngoing(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Android Developers Documentation :

> NotificationCompat.Builder
>   NotificationCompat.Builder (Context context)
>   This constructor was deprecated in API level 26.1.0. use
>   NotificationCompat.Builder(Context, String) instead. All posted
>   Notifications must pecify a NotificationChannel Id.

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder)
**Edit:**
Try the following :

1. Leave the `NotificationCompat.Builder` as it is now (with a string
   representing `NotificationChannel`) .
2. Comment out your if block where you create a notification channel
3. Replace your `NotificationManager` with  `NotificationManagerCompat` as the following :

   ```
   NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

               notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
   ```

Comment: just changed it and still not working

Comment: Did you add the same name of the channel you are creating ?

Comment: yes and still not working

Comment: I have updated my comment

Comment: still the same, not showin :(